# Grabbing everything past the domain in an NSURL?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsurl

This seems simple, but I haven't been able to find anything that does precisely what I'm looking for.

What I need is the ability the take an NSURL (or its NSString representation) and grab everything past the scheme and domain. So in the case of http://www.google.com/search?&q=cocoa, I need /search?&q=cocoa.

I can come close by cobbling together a string using [NSURL relativePath] and [NSURL query], but [NSURL query] leaves out question marks, and since the URLs I'm working with aren't guaranteed to have question marks I can't just add them back in myself.

So is there a nice, convenient way to grab everything past the scheme and domain that I've missed or am I going to have to pull it all apart and glue it back together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions etc. But in this case a custom solution might be best.

If your URL is always "http://..." then you need to locate the first "/" after the first 7 characters, and then take the string from there. Or you can just locate the 3rd "/"...

You can calculate the index of that "/" using one of the `rangeX` methods of `NSString`, and use the `substringFromIndex` method once you have it.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this exactly what `[NSURL relativeString]` does?

One [minor](http://books.google.ca/books?id=AeyX8GqdzPYC&pg=PA854&lpg=PA854&dq=NSURL%20%22relativeString%22&source=bl&ots=67dBP1VnLv&sig=oNoA-QljCUFTvtMNyYLhbQEAe4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0t9BUcSECdDl4AOWyIFI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=NSURL%20%22relativeString%22&f=false) note of caution on this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the URL doesn't have a question mark to denote its parameter string then all of the parameters should be returned as part of the path. For `NSURL` to return something from `‑query`, there *must* be a question mark in the URL.

The other things that can come after the path are `‑fragment` and `‑parameterString`. URLs basically break down like this:

```
scheme://user:password@host.domain.org:portnumber/path/file.htm;param1;param2?something=other&andmore=more#fragments
```

If `‑query` returns `nil` then there is no question mark.